# MySQL export chat table history

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables:

```
User table (user): user_id, username 
Chat table (chat): from_user_id, to_user_id, message, timestamp
```

I want to export chat history include the following fields and sort the result by timestamp (asc):

```
From_user_name, to_user_name, message, timestamp
```

I've tried a few ways to write the sql, but none of them worked. Can any one help with the sql?  Thank u!

Comment: Show what you've tried and why it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT from_user_name, to_user_name, message, timestamp
FROM chat c
join user f on c.from_user_id = f.user_id
join user t on c.to_user_id = t.user_id
order by timestamp asc
```